# Mapping JSON response field into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

**Response:**

`{"rsBody":
     [{"productId":11,
    "productImageUrl":"http:xxxx"},
    {"productId":9,
    "productImageUrl":"http:"xxxx"}]}`

I know this is a repeated question, but still asking cause not getting the right way to do it. I am getting some response from php server as `JSON` in an `array` which consists two objects. I want to `map` the element of both objects  `productImageUrl` in an `NSArray`. Resultant array should be somewhat like

`NSArray =[{@"url":"productImageUrl1"},{@"url":@"ProductImageUrl2"}, nil];`

productImageUrl1 = element of 1st object, productImageUrl2 = element of 2nd object.

I am parsing the response and able to to extract it from `rsBody`.

```
NSDictionary* response=(NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization     
JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];

NSArray *rsBody = [response objectForKey:@"rsBody"];
```

Comment: Now what's the problem ? Go ahead parse response and save into new array what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary* response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&tempError];

NSArray *rsBody = [response objectForKey:@"rsBody"];

for (NSDictionary *dict in rsBody)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictURL = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictURL setValue:[dict valueForKey:@"productImageUrl"] forKey:@"url"];
    [arr addObject:dictURL];
}

NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Cute Angel...will try n accept it as answer if it works.